# Boot repair recycles and does not fix boot

Tags: boot-repair

I am unable to boot into Ubuntu 14.04 any more. I downloaded the latest Live Cd and installed Boot-repair from there. I select the top option to fix it and it says "close programs". I close everything I see running. It goes through its process and then comes right back to a screen same as before asking to close all programs. Here is the log link.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17109446/)

Thanks